# Navigation Back Button Crash

Tags: ios, xcode

My application basically gets user input, adds it to tableview and goes to second view controller which has scrollview. User input is simply city name, and the app delivers detailed weather information in the scrollview.

App crashes when user scrolls then click native back button. Does any of you have any idea why this happens? By the way, if I do not scroll, then click back button does not crash.

My Project solution could be downloaded in the following link [Download Solution](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2Yf2EqUAx61RGUtcGREMXJSYzQ/edit)

Here is the crash screenshot
[image]

[image]

**Backtrace -**

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x6cac58, 0x000000010e1eb00b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 11, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
    frame #0: 0x000000010e1eb00b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 11
    frame #1: 0x000000010cb25c9c UIKit`-[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _notifyDidScroll] + 56
    frame #2: 0x000000010cb16262 UIKit`-[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 645
    frame #3: 0x000000010cb2ab9c UIKit`-[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary] + 1445
    frame #4: 0x000000010cb27d2b UIKit`-[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _stopScrollingNotify:pin:tramplingDragFlags:] + 417
    frame #5: 0x000000010cb16af6 UIKit`-[UIScrollView removeFromSuperview] + 32
    frame #6: 0x000000010caf0d19 UIKit`-[UIView dealloc] + 404
    frame #7: 0x000000010e1e98cd libobjc.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 591
    frame #8: 0x000000010e432346 CoreFoundation`_CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 22
    frame #9: 0x000000010e466473 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2051
    frame #10: 0x000000010e465a06 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    frame #11: 0x0000000110c539f0 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #12: 0x000000010ca92550 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1282
  * frame #13: 0x000000010c75c623 weather_app`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff534da2e0) + 115 at main.m:16
    frame #14: 0x000000010ecbf145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)
```

Comment: Go to the breakpoint navigator and set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions.  That will stop your program where it encounters the error instead of in the `main` routine.  Show the resulting stack trace.  (Type 'bt' at the (lldb) prompt in the debug console and paste the result into the question.)

Comment: I would also suggest you to set your delegates -  `<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSource>`

Comment: Hello Philip, raurora just added backtrace.

Comment: It looks like there's a message being sent to an object that no longer exists.  (Do you have a UIScrollViewDelegate defined...and released too soon, maybe?)  The next debugging trick would be to turn on zombies in your build scheme.  That should tell you what the released object is.

Comment: @casillas Did you find a solution yet? I'd be happy to help.

Comment: @raurora, now I have not got it work

Comment: @casillas Great, do not hesistate to answer your own question. Go ahead - stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I have not found the solution.

Comment: @casillas Posted. If this has answered your question, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark icon. This takes it off the "unanswered" list and increases the chance of people answering your future questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Run > Arguments > Environment
    Variables > Set `NSZombieEnabled` as `YES`.

2) Build and run the app. And, that's what you should see in the Debug area -

```
weather_app[19317:4849510] *** -[ViewController scrollViewDidScroll:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7f9f4240bea0
```

3) Likewise, you can use Instruments to intercept the `NSZombie`.

[image]

---

4) Look in the `[ViewController scrollViewDidScroll:]` method. I'd leave it for you to think on how/why the control should not sent to the deallocated object in this method.

5) Get rid of this method - `scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView`. And, update your indicator in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` method. That should run your program without crash.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    pageControlBeingUsed = NO;

    // Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

6) Also, there are many warnings in your program like not setting delegates -  `<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSource>` and a missing `self.scrollView.delegate = self;`

Hope, this was helpful.